# integration of ssl in cakephp 3

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, cakephp3

I wanted my application to use https instead of http, so after some research i made some changes in .htaccess file, now my file looks something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.in/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

after this my website is on https instead of http as required but it has stopped functioning, it is not able to include other php files, unable to load resources be it css, js or img.
I googled a lot but still getting the same error

```
include(menu.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP/Template/Pages/home.ctp, line 1]

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

this error is coming for all the resources

looking for help, m just a newbie
Thanks in advance
Tarun Madaan

Comment: Try this code in your .htaccess file RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: i tried, it didn't work, can you please suggest something else? and when we say HTTPS off, does it mean we are turning off the https request?